# C argument conversion

Tags: c, arguments

First,I have to say that I am new to C programming. What I'm trying to do is write a program that takes an argument input and converts it into an integer and then returns its value. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int fromArgv = NULL;  /* holds value from argv[1] */
   fromArgv = atoi (argv[1]);    /* convert argv[1] to int */

   /* if incorrect no. of arguments entered */
   if (argc != 2) {
   fprintf (stderr, "error: wrong number of arguments\n");
   exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   } 

   return fromArgv;
}
```

I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
ex1.c: In function ‘main’:
ex1.c:6:18: error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: As a sidenote, I just can't help wondering why do you try to get the argument's value first, but only then check whether it actually had been given - or not (with that `argc != 2`)

Comment: As it seems to be for ugly casting around today: `int fromArgv = (int) NULL;` would work.

Comment: @alk Why it just can't be written like `int fromArgv = atoi(argv[1])`, I wonder.

Comment: int can not contain NULL (is not a pointer), it is not a good idea to return other than 0 when program doesn't fail, better to printf("%d\n", fromArgv)

Comment: Because there is no answer to your first question? ;-> @raina77ow

Comment: OT: Don't use `atoi()` unless you are sure to not pass something to it, which whould evaluate to `0`, as `0` is also returned on error. Go for `strtol()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
int fromArgv = NULL;
```

I believe `NULL` is usually defined as `(void *) 0`, which is a pointer.  You're assigning this pointer to an `int` variable, which gives you the error.

However, there's no need to initialize `fromArgv` in this case.  You can just do:

```
int fromArgv;  /* holds value from argv[1] */
fromArgv = atoi (argv[1]);    /* convert argv[1] to int */
```

or even just

```
int fromArgv = atoi (argv[1]);    /* convert argv[1] to int */
```

What you do have to do, however, is make sure `argv[1]` exists before you access it so you don't get a segfault if the user does not enter any command-line arguments.  You should move your `if (argc != 2)` test before the assignment of `fromArgv`.

Comment: `atoi()` doesn't like `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining this to me. Now I understand and it also works.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` is a null *pointer* constant , and you attempt to assign it to an *integer* value (`fromArgv`), therefore your compiler reports a warning.

The following initialization works fine:

```
fromArgv = 0;
```

Although, it is useless, since you are modifying the value of your variable on the next line:

```
int fromArgv = atoi(argv[1]);
```

By the way, it is a bad idea to return this kind of value from `main` (it is often reserved to error codes), and you are cbecking the number of arguments too late.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by others, you are initializing an integer with a "null pointer" (that from a type point of view is a pointer), which is wrong. You wanted to initialize it to zero,

```
       int fromArgv = 0;
```

Then, you should pick the argument and convert it to int **after** and not before checking the number of arguments. So, you should move the "atoi" line after the `if (argc != 2)` part.

Consider also the possibility to use `strtol` instead of `atoi`. The former allows you to check if the conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

u cant initialize fromArgv to NULL because NULL is a pointer and u are assigning it to int
just change the line as int fromArgv ;

Answer (score 0):

Why do you ever have to initialize fromArgv ?

just

```
int fromArgv = atoi(arg[1]);
```

should be working fine